# Multiple web views on single screen/activity in android

Tags: android, webview

Can one have more than one web view on a single screen/activity in an android app? Im new to android dev, and Im thinking of building an app where for instance the top quarter of the screen uses a webview which loads html,css, and js from local files packaged with the app (this will be the logo and menu items), and another scrollable web view occupies the bottom 3/4 of the screen with data retrieved from the internet. Similar to how the Twitter for Android app seems to work. Im not sure whether that app uses multiple web views though.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure I understood why you want to have multiple WebView's but, yes, you can have several in the same Layout.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could do that..the best way may be, using XML layout

1. Add 2 weviews within a linear layout using android:layout_weight="1"
   So you get 2 webviews occupying half space each. You can give it accordingly.
2. Now, use findViewById() in the program and get the ID of the webviews.

So you get both views in a single activity.
Let me know if you have any other doubts.

Cheers

Nithin

Comment: how to add 3 webview in main.xml

Comment: Simple, just put 3 webviews in the main.xml, and give android:layout_weight="1" for three of them. That will take care.